# Android Studio installation failed on Mac

Tags: android-studio

When I try to install Android Studio both from .pkg or brew, they both fail with the following message after I click the app. I can't into the wizard setup process.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV4O1.png)

Previously, I have solved this problem by adding a "AndroidStudio2023.1" folder in "Application Support" folder, but this time it does not work either.

Hope I can successfully install Android Studio